# React - variables not getting updated in createOrder function for PayPal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal

I want to pass the selectedOption var to the creatOrder function. the selectedOption will be chosen from the user and then I want to pass this to the paypal createOrder. The thing is that when i click on paypal button it  alwayse retirves the deafult value of the selectedOption which is credits: 10, price: 4.99. even if the user change the options.

I don't understand the issue why the update state of selectedOption  is not reflected in the createOrder.

```
function CombinedPaymentForm({ email }) {
  const creditOptions = [
    { credits: 10, price: 4.99 },
    { credits: 20, price: 9.99 },
    { credits: 30, price: 14.99 },
    { credits: 50, price: 24.99 },
  ];

  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(creditOptions[0]);
  
  const handleOptionChange = (selectedCredits) => {
    const option = creditOptions.find(option => option.credits === selectedCredits);
    setSelectedOption(option);
  };


 const createOrder = (data,selectedOption) => {
   
      // This will be executed after the handleOptionChange function has updated the selectedOption state.
      return fetch(fullUrl, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          service: {
            description: "My first payment",
            cost: selectedOption.price,
          }
        }),
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((order) => order.id);
  
  };

  const onApprove = (data) => {
    return fetch(fullUrlCapture, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        orderID: data.orderID,
        email: email,
        credits: selectedOption.credits,
        price: selectedOption.price
      })
    })
    .then((response) => { 
      console.log("payment successful");
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => console.log("data", data));


  return (
    <div>
      <label>
        Email:
        <input type="email" value={email} readOnly />
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faDollarSign} />
        النقاط المراد شرائها
        <select
          value={selectedOption.credits}
          onChange={(e) => handleOptionChange(parseInt(e.target.value))}
        >
          {creditOptions.map((option) => (
            <option key={option.credits} value={option.credits}>
              {option.credits} credits - ${option.price}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </label>
      <br />
      <PayPalScriptProvider options={paypalOptions}>
 
        <PayPalButtons
          createOrder={(data) => createOrder(data,selectedOption)}
          onApprove={(data) => onApprove(data)}
        />
     
      </PayPalScriptProvider>
    </div>
  );

  };

}
```

If i console.log(selectedOption) inside the createOrder it keeps returing the initnal value

Comment: Since `selectedOption` is a state variable, you should not have to send it into the function `createOrder = (data,selectedOption)`, it should be available already.